# Compute the determinant of M

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $(x_1,...,x_n)$ be real numbers and M be an $n \times n$ matrix whose its column is given by the entries $x_i,x_i^2, x_i^3,...x_i^n$. Compute the determinant of M.

I computed the formula for the determinant of M in terms of $x_1...x_n$ but I wonder if I can find a specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tsemo Aristide is absolutely correct, you can follow that link and also [The Proof for your specific case here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant). However, this is a different kind of explanation for what you have, which is not a proof but I think it might help you better grasp the concept.

At the first glance, this looks very similar to the Vandermonde matrix; except we have

$$ M =  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc} 
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & \cdots & x_n
   \\x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 &\cdots & x_n^2\\
   \vdots &  & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
   x_1 ^n & x_2^n & x_3^n & \cdots &x_n^n \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
Now let us consider the Vandermonde's matrix which is

$$V = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & x_1 & x_1^2& \cdots & x_1^{n-1}\\
   1 & x_2 & x_2^2 &\cdots & x_2^{n-1}\\
   \vdots &  & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
   1 & x_n& x_n & \cdots &x_n^{n-1}\\ 
  \end{array} } \right]$$
As we can see, there are very closely related; so we want to find the matrix $X$ so that 
$$VX=M$$ and in that case the determinant of $M$ will be
 $$\det(M) = \det(V) \cdot \det(X)$$
Now let us look at an example of a $2 \times 2$ by $2 \times 2$ matrices, so assume that we have :
$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  a & 0\\
   0 & b \\
  \end{array} } \right]
   \times 
   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 1\\
   2& 2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]   
  = 
   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  a & a\\
   2b& 2b \\
  \end{array} } \right]  
$$ 
So we can see that by multiplying this diagonal matrix by a the square matrix, we can multiply each component of the first row by $a$ and second row by $b$. Now this is exactly what we want in order to go from our the Vandermonde matrix to the given matrix; furthermore this is very beneficial since we know the determinant of the diagonal matrix is the multiplication of the diagonals and we know the Vandermonde's determinant. So to get $M$ we will have

$VX = N $ where $$X =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   x_1 & 0 & 0& \cdots & 0\\
   0 & x_2 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
   \vdots &  & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
   0&0 &0 & \cdots &x_n\\   
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
Now
$$VX = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n\\
   x_2 & x_2^2 & x_2^2 &\cdots & x_2^n\\
   \vdots &  & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
   x_n  & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots &x_n^n\\ 
  \end{array} } \right] = N
  $$
 This is almost what we want except we have the transpose of this matrix, so $(VX)^T = M$. Also, for a square matrix, the determinant of the transpose is the same as the determinant of the matrix, we will have :
  $$\det(X)\cdot\det(V) = \prod_{1\leq i \leq n}x_i \cdot \prod_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n} (x_j - x_i) = \det(M^T) = \det(M)$$

Again this is not a proof, but I hope this clarified some stuff from both of the links.

Comment: Thank you @Ali Heydari that makes sense!

Comment: I believe a much simpler version would be:
Assume $x_1 \neq 0$. Then take $x_1^i$ from the $i^{th}$ column to get the vandermond determinant with entries $\frac{x_2}{x_1} , \frac{x_3}{x_1}, ...,  \frac{x_n}{x_1}$. And then solve for $x_1 = 0$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use this determinant formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

take $x_{n+1}=0$ and develop the Vandermonde $(n+1)\times (n+1)$-determinant relatively to the last line.